# Página de inicio de sesión con Django y Vue 3

Tags: django, vue.js, login, autenticación

Estoy intentando crear una aplicación en Django para el backend y Vue.js para el frontend, totalmente separados.

Actualmente necesito crear una autenticación de usuario en Vue según los usuarios registrados en los modelos de Django, pero no sé cómo hacerlo. Quisiera que el usuario pueda autenticarse según los modelos de Django y luego almacenar esa sesión de alguna forma en Vue para desplegar el contenido correspondiente.

**Notas:**

- Con los modelos de Django me refiero al modelo estándar de usuario. *`(class models.User)`*.
- Para el FrontEnd utilizo Vue3.
- Actualmente cuento con una API Rest para controlar ciertos objetos de mis modelos, por ahora permite realizar un CRUD básico de los datos.

1. ¿Es posible llamar métodos de mis `*views.py*` desde el FrontEnd mediante la API Rest?
2. ¿Es posible obtener desde Vue mediante la API Rest si el usuario está logueado en Django? (*`is_authenticated`*)

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si bien entiendo la pregunta, creo que el hecho de que no pongas tus modelos, o lo que has intentado, hace que sea una pregunta inválida. Por otro lado CREERIA que es una pregunta basada en opiniones. Te recomiendo que muestres lo que tenes en el backend, la version de Vue que usas, y si intentaste algo desde el front, que también lo coloques.

Comment: Editado para entregar más detalles, gracias. @AgustinG.

Comment: Tu publicación es muy amplia y no se ajusta al formato esperado en [ask], pues considera que incluyes múltiples dudas a la vez, en una de dichas preguntas solicitas sugerencias de recursos externos y finalmente no hay un punto de partida como tal que a la comunidad le indique que has intentado. Recomiendo revises  el [tour] y como aportar un [mcve]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.